# Не получается сверстать элемент

Tags: html, css

Должно получится как на скрине

[image: Футер]
HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
  <img src="http://euroingridients.monotone.by/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/location.png"  >
    <span>4-й переулок Кольцова д.51, офис 501
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <img src="http://euroingridients.monotone.by/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/phone.png">
    +32332234234
  +34234234234</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="http://euroingridients.monotone.by/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/phone.png">
    iwenik@gmail.com</div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><img src="http://euroingridients.monotone.by/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/phone.png"></div>
  <div class="col-md-5"><img src="http://euroingridients.monotone.by/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/phone.png"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://euroingridients.monotone.by/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/phone.png"></div>
  <div class="col-md-7"><img src="http://euroingridients.monotone.by/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/phone.png"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div .row {
  display: inline-block;
}

div .col-md-1 {
  width:100%;
  float: left;
}

div .col-md-2 {
  width:100%;
  display: inline;
}

div .col-md-3 {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item .fa {
  font-size: 2.6em;
}

.item div {
  padding: 6px;
}

.item:last-child .fa {
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="items">

  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>4 переулок кользова</p>
      <p>д 51 офис 711</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>8 800 000 000 00</p>
      <p>8 800 000 000 00</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>mail@mail.ru</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на bootstrap. 
Если так, то вы не понимаете принципа его работы.
Цифра после "md" в названии класса означает не порядковый номер блока, а занимаемую им ширину.

Ширина строки (row) 12 колонок.
Если посмотреть на макет внимательно, то можно увидеть, что он состоит из 4 блоков шириной в 3 колонки. В первых трех блоках — иконка и текст, в четвертом блоке — 4 иконки.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
  
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
  
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
  
  </div>
</div>
```